# Number System Conversions with strtol

Tags: performance, c, converting

### Description

The code uses `strtol()` to convert text that represents a value in a given base into an integer.
It takes three arguments from the command line, including the string and the base. The string may begin with an arbitrary amount of white space followed by a optional `-` or `+`. If the base is 0 or 16, the string may include `0x` or `0X` and it would be taken as hexadecimal, otherwise a zero base will be taken as decimal.

From [`strtol()`'s manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html):

> (In  bases  above  10,  the letter  'A'  in  either uppercase or lowercase represents 10, 'B' represents 11, and so forth, with 'Z' representing 35.)

I compiled it under the flags `-Wall -g -Winit-self -Wredundant-decls -Wfloat-equal -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-declarations -Wswitch-default -Wmain -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -Wall`
and it didn't issue any warnings.

### Questions

1. Style review (indentation, comments, readability, etc.)
2. Is there room for more error-checking? Have I forgotten anything except for an invalid base (that I remembered now)?
3. How could it be improved?

### Sample input/output

Examples of successful conversions:

1. ```
   ./a.out 102438 10
   Success [102438].
   ```
2. ```
   ./a.out 0403 8
   Success [259].
   ```
3. ```
   ./a.out 0x41 16
   Success [65].
   ```
4. ```
   ./a.out 00101010 2.
   Success [42].
   ```

Examples of errors:

1. ```
   ./a.out acbdavikf 2
   Error: No digits were found.
   ```
2. ```
   ./a.out 123acbdavikf 0
   Error: Trailing junk after number.
   ```
3. ```
   ./a.out 124235898259250270295 10
   strtol: Numerical result out of range
   ```
4. ```
   ./a.out  -124235898259250270295 10
   strtol: Numerical result out of range
   ```

### Code

```
/* The program converts any base number to its equivalent decimal number. */
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
 
static void convert_to_long(const char *nptr, const int base);
static void *error_checked_malloc(int size);
static void print_error_msg(const char *command);
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *command = error_checked_malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
    command = argv[0];
 
    if (argc != 3)
        print_error_msg(command);
 
    char *str = argv[1];
    int base = atoi(argv[2]);

    convert_to_long(str, base);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
 
///===========================================================================================================================================================
static void convert_to_long(const char *nptr, const int base)
{
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;     /* To distinguish success/failure after call. */
    long int val = strtol(nptr, &endptr, base);

    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if (nptr == endptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No digits were found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (*endptr != '\0')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Trailing junk after number.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (errno == ERANGE)    /* Checks both over/under-flow */
    {
        perror("strtol");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Success [%ld].\n", val);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
 
///==================================================================================================================================================================
static void *error_checked_malloc(int size)
{
    char *ptr = malloc(size);
    if (!ptr)
    {
        perror("Malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ptr;
}
 
///=====================================================================================================================================================================
static void print_error_msg(const char *command)
{
    printf("Usage: <%s> <string> <base>\n", command);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: the name of error_checked_malloc() sounds like it is meant to guard against things like use-after-frees and double-frees. In GNU code, it is conventional to call this function `xmalloc`, and I suggest you adopt this name

Comment: Apart from the zero case, the functions do match. Convention adopted.

Comment: Minor point: the code doesn't convert **between** bases; it converts **text** that represents a value in a given base into an integer. Neither the integer nor the value that it holds has a base. It's only when you **display** the integer (which the code in the question doesn't do) that a base is involved; you can display the **value** in base 2, base 8, base 10, base 16, or any other base you might like.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, that's correct. I would change that claim in the question.

Comment: I don't have the time for a full answer, but the most grievous issue is that you do not separate the "core" logic from the I/O (driver). Try to write the conversion function that would be useful as a library => it'll allow you writing unit-tests, notably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Style review(indentation, comments, readability, etc.)

**Noise**

`const` serves no purpose with `const int base` in the `static void convert_to_long(const char *nptr, const int base);` *declaration*.

Simplify

```
// static void convert_to_long(const char *nptr, const int base);
static void convert_to_long(const char *nptr, int base);
```

`const` with an object has limited value in function *definitions*.

**Allocate to the referenced object, not the type**

Allocating to the refenced object is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// command = error_checked_malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
command = error_checked_malloc(64 * sizeof command[0]);
```

**`else` not needed**

Simplify

```
//else
//{
//    printf("Success [%ld].\n", val);
//    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
//}

printf("Success [%ld].\n", val);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

**`exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` is troublesome in a helper function.**

Better to return success from `main()`.

**Excessive vertical white-space**

**Inconsistent indent**

`if (argc != 3) print_error_msg(command);` deserves `{}`.

---

> Is there room for more error-checking? Have I forgotten anything except for an invalid base(that I remembered now)?

**Error messages deserve to print on `stderr`**

```
// printf("Usage: <%s> <string> <base>\n", command);
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: <%s> <string> <base>\n", command);
```

**`atoi()` lacks checking**

Non-numeric input, numeric text input with trailing text and out of `int` range values expose weakness with the simplistic `aoti()`.  Consider `strtol()`.

**`base` not in expected range**

With `strtol(nptr, &endptr, base);`, a base value of negative, 1, more than 36 are all problematic and undetected here.

**Maintain case**

```
// perror("Malloc");
perror("malloc");
```

---

> How could it be improved?

**Allow trailing whitespace**

Instead of `if (*endptr != '\0')`, perhaps first march down the string if it has optional trailing white-space.  This simplifies testing a *line* of input from `fgets()`.

**Allocation deserves to use type `size_t` for size, not `int`**

**Zero**

`error_checked_malloc(0)` should not result in an error.

**Negative**

`error_checked_malloc(some negative value)` should certainly result in an error.  As is, code may successfully allocate a huge block.

**`convert_to_long()` surprisingly prints**

Aside from errors, I'd expect `convert_to_long()` to convert and let the calling code do any printing.

**Allow input to omit base**

When *base* argument missing, simply assume 0 (or 10).

Comment: You raised some good points. I wasn't aware of the other complications pertaining to malloc, but would it be applicable to test for a negative value in this context? Could the filename/command be rendered negative somehow?

Comment: @HarisSalam As `size_t` is some _unsigned_ type, perhaps `static void *error_checked_malloc(size_t size) { if (size == 0) { return NULL; } char *ptr = malloc(size);  if (!ptr) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } return ptr; }`

Comment: "Could the filename/command be rendered negative somehow?" is unclear.  Please restate.

Comment: I was referring to the NEGATIVE section as size_t couldn't be unsigned and malloc could allocate a huge block of memory successfully. I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

chux and Toby already made many excellent points. I want to add one:

### Make the output useful by being less verbose

Being verbose when printing an error message is helpful, but don't be verbose when your program is running successfully. Consider that someone might want to use your program in a script, or perhaps that you as a user want to copy&paste the result to somewhere else. If you print:

```
Success [42].
```

Then it's harder to copy&paste (since it's now easier to accidentily select unwanted characters on this line), but it's especially harder to use in a script: if you are just interested in the resulting value 42, then you'd have to run the output of your program through some other commands just to strip away the `Success [` and `].`. Just output the value without anything else:

```
42
```

Answer (score 6):

[Everything that chux said](/a/281511/75307), and:

The memory allocation is unused and leaked.  Look at this:

> ```
>     char *command = error_checked_malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
>
>     command = argv[0];
> ```

Now that `command` points to the zeroth argument, there's no way to access or free the memory we allocated.  Replace this with

```
    char *command = argv[0];
```

BTW, `sizeof (char)` is necessarily 1 (since `sizeof` measures in units of `char`), so that multiplication is just noise.

Comment: Now I understand why valgrind was complaining about freeing illegal memory. Thanks, Toby.